# Why doesn't this basic anime.js work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I am starting to learn Anime.JS. To see how it worked, I copied some very basic sample code from their [documentation website](http://animejs.com/documentation/). Weirdly, the square is not animating to the right 250px like it should be...

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="anime.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="cssSelector">
      <div class="line">
        <div class="square el"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background-color: #232323;
}

.square{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

And Javascript

```
var cssSelector = anime({
  targets: '#cssSelector .el',
  translateX: 250
});
```

I see the square but there is no animation. The program *does* read the anime.min.js because there is no error message in the console.

Comment: It works on mine: https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/980j4591/ Are you sure it is loaded? Also make sure you run your code after the page is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I believe is that you are trying to run your code before the page is loaded.

Add this:

```
function main(){
    anime({
        targets: '#cssSelector .el',
        translateX: 250
    });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", main);
```

Then it should work: https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/980j4591/